# Finding area bounded by $y=2 \sin{x} - 1$ and $y = \frac{x}{\pi}$

Tags: calculus, integration

**[UPDATE in bold]**

> Find the area bounded by $y=2 \sin{x} - 1$ and $y = \frac{x}{\pi}$ **for the range $0 \le x \le \pi$**

I don't really know how to start... How can I find the intercepts of the curve/lines?

I get the 2 equations equals each other:

$$
2 \sin x - 1 = \frac{x}{\pi}
$$
$$
2 \sin x - 1 - \frac{x}{\pi} = 0
$$
$$
2 \pi \sin x - \pi - x = 0 
$$

Then what do I do?

Comment: Try plotting the curves to get a feel for what the question asks you to do.

Comment: How many solutions do you find to the pair of equations?  Most you will not be able to find algebraically.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2sinx-1+and+x%2Fpi+between+-9+and+8) shows five places where the equations coincide, and four bits of area to be considered. This is not an obvious calculation.

Comment: In view of the other comments, I'd advise checking to make sure that the problem is being quoted correctly.

Comment: Ok updated the qn

Comment: I'm still not convinced the problem is quoted correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Post has been edited as per comment from GerryMyerson.

Area bound by 2 functions $f1$ and $f2$ can be found using integration of the function $f1-f2$

You must first identify the points where the 2 curves intersect in the are you are interested $0 \le x \le \pi$ in your case. This is what you started doing.

so you need to find values of x that satisfies:

$2 \pi \sin x - \pi - x = 0$

There are different ways you can do this depending on your background and tools available to you.

For example, you could either:

1. Draw the curves
2. Use numerical analysis
3. Expand the function using series
4. Use a software

Using 1,4 I found the points where the 2 curves intersect to have x values of:
x1=0.647 and x2=2.142 (good for 2 decimal points)

Define $D(x) =  2 \sin x - 1 - \frac{x}{\pi}$

$A=ABS(A1) + ABS(A2) + ABS(A3)$

Where:

$A1=\int_{0}^{0.647} D(x)$

$A2=\int_{0.647}^{2.142} D(x)$

$A3=\int_{2.142}^{\pi} D(x)$

The diagram below may help you.

[image]

Comment: What about between 2.142 and $\pi$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks for your correct observation. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

The area between the curves $y= f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$, for the domain $a \leq x \leq b$, is given by
$$\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)| dx.$$

Here's the reasoning behind this formula: the area between curves $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is the same as the area between $f(x)-g(x)$ and the $x$-axis. (Intuitively, if you think of the original area as a mound of dirt, you're allowing the dirt to fall until it is flush with the ground; doing so doesn't change the area of the dirt.)

The integral of $f(x)-g(x)$ gives you the *signed* area under the curve. To get the unsigned area, you have to stick in an absolute value.

So the procedure for solving this kind of problem is as follows:

1. Determine whether $f$ and $g$ cross anywhere in the domain; in other words, find all $x$ in the domain for which $f(x)-g(x)=0$.
2. Split the integral above into $n+1$ pieces, where $n$ is the number of crossing point you found in step 1, so that on each piece $f(x)-g(x)$ is either all positive, or all negative.
3. On each piece, replace the absolute value with $+$ or $-$, as appropriate.
4. Integrate up each piece and add together the results to get the final answer.

Let me know if anything is unclear, or if you need more help.

Comment: Step 1 is the hard part, for this problem.

Comment: For this particular problem you're not going to find exact solutions; use a graphing calculator (or Wolfram Alpha) to find the approximate crossings.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

1. Try to find the number of intersections between the curves.
2. Call the points of intersection $x_1, x_2, x_3,\ldots,x_n$
3. Try to calculate $$\int_0^{x_1} f(x) - g(x)\, dx + \int_{x_1}^{x_2} g(x) - f(x)\, dx +\cdots+(-1)^{n}\int_{x_n}^{\pi} f(x) - g(x)\, dx$$

Comment: Step 1 is the hard part, for this problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson No it is not. Look at $f(x)=2\sin x - 1 -x/\pi$, it is easy to see that $f$ has at least 2 zeros (since $f(0)<0, f(\pi/2)>0, f(\pi)<0$). Also, $f'(x)=2\cos x -1/\pi$ which has exactly one zero in $[0,\pi]$. Now suppose you had more than two zeros in the interval - the mean value theorem would then give more at least two zeros for $f'$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The above would at least give an expression for the area.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not read carefully. What I meant to point out was that in this problem finding the actual intersection points is the hard part. So it's really step 3, where you need the values of the $x_i$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I agree, I also agree to your last comment to the problem - there might be an error in the quote of the homework.